# Why Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:?

Tags: java, eclipse, classnotfoundexception

I run my software through Eclipse. Yesterday everything was fine. I made not changes to the code but today, when I am trying to run it again I get the following error messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: coloredtrails/CTListener
    at test.DemoPlayer1.createAndShowGUI(DemoPlayer1.java:23)
    at test.DemoPlayer1.main(DemoPlayer1.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: coloredtrails.CTListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Why it does not see the class? What could be the reason of that? How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: have you tried clean-->build your project?

Comment: @Harry Joy, thank you for the advise! You "saved my life"! :) Now it works. It was so annoying that it stopped to work close to the deadline. Now it works!

Comment: This is a good example why not to work with eclipse...

Comment: Often this is due to Eclipse known-issue behavior, not the JVM itself. 1) Make sure to use the fully qualified package name (*x.y.z.MyClass*) of your object under *'Main Resource'* in Eclipse's Run/Debug Configuration 2)  Try Eclipse *'Build All'* instead of *'Build Project'*. 3) Only then start checking your classpath, directories etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `NoClassDefFoundError` (almost) always means that your classpath is wrong. Make sure that your classpath includes the base directory of the `coloredtrails` package. (Ofcourse, also make sure that the file `coloredtrails\CTListener.class` actually exists).

When running from the command line:

You can set the classpath by setting the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, or by specifying it with the `-cp` or `-classpath` option on the command line when you run your program. For example:

```
java -cp C:\MyProject\classes coloredtrails.CTListener
```

*edit* - Looking at the stack trace and seeing `URLClassLoader` in there makes me think that you are trying to run a Java applet. To learn how to correctly deploy applets, so that all classes the applet needs can be found, see this tutorial: [Deploying an Applet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html).

Comment: I tried this and many other alternatives and didn't work.
**Deleting the workspace** only worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, my Eclipse (Indigo on MacOSX) does that, expecially if I do changes (removing files, moving them around) to the project structure on the filsystem directly.

Basically, eclipse cannot find the source folder anymore, so he doesn't compile the source but tries to run it anyway (all this without a warning or a reference to the problem).

To fix it, remove the source folder from the build path (=right click on the src folder under the project in the package explorer, then choose "Build-path->Remove from Build-path". Then, add it again (=right click on the folder under the project in the package explorer and choose "Add to build-path"). This makes the src folder "visible" to the compiler again and fixes the problem.

Comment: Alternatively refresh all the files in eclipse (Shortcut F5 on the root folder in your project).

Comment: I had the same issue with Mavericks. I only could solve it by **deleting the workspace**.

Comment: Also tried to re-add the src folder, but didn't work. Creating a new workspace did the trick.